# Zurb Foundation 6 - Change textarea background on focus

Tags: css, textarea, zurb-foundation-6

I've changed my background color of my tectarea from contact form. However when I click inside to type a message, the background turns to white. I tried everything but I couldn't figure it out how this works. Some one know how to fixe the abckground to jsut one color?

```
#contato input, textarea{
  background-color: #333333;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zurb Foundation have a specific `textarea:focus` background color declaration, so you will have to override it:

```
#contato input, textarea, textarea:focus {
  background-color: #333333;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```